# Get contents of child_added while watching firebaseArray

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, watch

I have a simple private chat, but with different type of messages, so when i send to server json structure I pass message type too.

```
$scope.messages = fireChat.firebaseArray;
$scope.addMessage = function(e) {

    //ADD TO FIREBASE
    $scope.messages.$add({
        uid: $scope.authData.uid,
        text: $scope.msg,
        timestamp: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        type: 'msg'
    });

    $scope.msg = ""; //RESET MESSAGE

};
```

As you can see there is property 'type'.

Now i'd like to watch for any new messages. As in documentation there is a watch API function, but it only returns the `ID` of the record/message. I'd like to get the contents of the message and check what is `type` is there and then according to that run other js functions.

```
$scope.messages.$watch(function (data) {
    console.log("angularfire watch");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.event);
    console.log(data.key);
    console.log(data.prevChild);
});
```

Above would return only `child_added` `-Jp6KZWlyDtDETz8Agpr` and `-Jp6KZWlyDtDETz8ospr`. As you see, no body under the key
Is there a possibility to get a the key contents? So I could do for example

```
switch (key.type) {
  case 'paid':
    animate_paid();
}
```

**Edit:**

```
$scope.messages.$watch(function (data) {
    console.log("angularfire watch");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.event);
    console.log(data.key);
    console.log($scope.messages.$getRecord(data.key));
});
```

The above code works finally

Comment: Not an anwer, but *please* consider replacing all those `console.log`s with the approach highlighted here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro. A simple `<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>` in your view, replaces all of the `console.log`s and removes the need for `$watch` in your example.

Comment: You should probably not be trying to capture child_added events. This defeats the purpose in using AngularFire to manage the events on your behalf. If the goal is to manipulate data, then utilize the [$extend method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html) and tap into the $$ methods accordingly. Otherwise, let AngularFire handle the synchronization and just use it as a local array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $getRecord to do it:

```
console.log($scope.messages.$getRecord(data.key));
```

You can look through the api for arrays here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question, getRecord throws `TypeError: Cannot read property '$getRecord' of undefined`

Comment: Whoops, it should be messages

Comment: Thanks, it works! My bad too, I didn't see the spelling of variable name i declared myself. Probably cause I was in a rush for MVP and presentation yesterday. Works like charm now!